# Microsoft Teams Graph API get teams a user is a member of without admin consent?

Tags: rest, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to get a list of teams for a given user without needing `admin_consent`. Is this possible? I assumed that if a user consents to an application and I get an access token for them that I would be able to request information scoped to that single user, like what teams they are a part of.

But after looking at the api permissions [/me/joinedTeams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) it looks like `admin_consent` is needed for all of them, which is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out due to some API weirdness you can use `/me/memberOf` without `admin_consent` to at least get the ID's of all teams the user has permissions to.

`/me/joinedTeams` however will just return a `403 Forbidden`.

Also if you want to map the "external"? id for a team returned from `/me/memberOf` to the "internal" id that a Teams message will have (begins with `19:`) you can still use the `/teams/{id}` endpoint also without any admin credentials to get just the internal ID for the team.

Answer (score 0):

To get the the teams the user is a member of is possible from application as well

URL-> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/joinedTeams](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7BUserId%7D%7D/joinedTeams)

Authorization -> BEARER {{AppAccessToken}}

To get the app access token

URL -> [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BTenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

Body-> x-www-urlform-encoded

grant_type-> client_credentials

client_id -> {{ClientID}}

client_secret -> {{ClientSecret}}

scope -> https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

you will need you app to have permission

1- > teams.setting.user.all

2 -> teams.read.basic.all

see if some other permissions are also required But this worked for me.